# Blazor WebAssembly 3.2.0 Build failed

Tags: .net-core, blazor-webassembly

Please i have recently ran into this error trying to build my blazor app.

```
Severity Code Description Project File  Line Suppression State
Error   MSB3027 Could not copy "C:\Users\verky\.nuget\packages\microsoft.aspnetcore.components.webassembly.server\3.2.0\tools\BlazorDebugProxy\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DebugProxy.deps.json" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\BlazorDebugProxy\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DebugProxy.deps.json". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    BlazorMovies.Server C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets 4643
```

Please can someone help me out. I have been on this for a week now.
Have searched over and over without help.

Deleted bin and obj folders over and over, I have uninstalled visual studio and reinstalled, still doesn't help.

Comment: Dummy question, is your project not running? To make sure that's the case, do you get the same error the first time you try to run the project after the restart?

Comment: No not running sir. It doesn't run after restart

Comment: Do you have a repro project you can share on GitHub?

Comment: Ok sir. I will. I have copied the project to another laptop it worked only on my visual studio that it is not running.

Comment: Do I understand you right then, that you project works if you try to run it from CLI - using `dotnet run` ?

Comment: No sir. It didn't work. Gives me this error: The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

Comment: Ok, will wait for the repro project to try out.

Comment: "It doesn't run after restart" - does that mean that it runs once?

Comment: No ever since the error showed up once. No project new or old has been able to start

Comment: @Artak here is the repo: https://github.com/cleancodelover/BlazorApp1.git

Comment: Also note that the project works on any other machine except mine. I am wondering maybe how I can reset completely Blazor settings on my VS because DotNet Core project works except blazor

Comment: It does work for me and I'm not sure how to help, really. Try to update your Visual Studio to the latest version. Not sure that's the problem or not, but that may help. Also, install the latest 3.1 SDK update. Just things to try. Other than that, sorry, but nothing else I can think of.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I have updated the visual studio completely. But still getting the same error. How do remove Blazor Templates from Visual studio, let me try removing and adding it again because the error is there only for blazor apps, dotnet core mvc and anyother one works fine. @Artak

Comment: You can use `dotnet new -u Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Templates::3.2.0` to install the WebAssembly templates.